# Get attribute from current page

Tags: spring, hyperlink, getattribute

TaskController

```
     @GetMapping("/admin/addTask")
        public String task(String email, Model model, HttpSession session){
            session.setAttribute("email",email);
            model.addAttribute("task",new Task());
            return "task";
        }

        @PostMapping("/admin/addTask")
        public String addTask(@Valid Task task, BindingResult bindingResult,HttpSession session){
            if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
                return "task";
            }
            String emailik = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
            taskService.addTask(task,userService.findOne(emailik));
            return "redirect:/admin/users";
        }
         @GetMapping("/admin/usertask")
            public String getEmail(User email, Model model,HttpSession session){
                model.addAttribute("task",taskService.findUserTask(email));
                model.addAttribute("emaail",session.getAttribute("email"));
                return "usertasklist";
            }
```

users list controller

```
        @GetMapping("admin/users")
        public String listUsers(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String name) {
            model.addAttribute("users",userService.findByName(name));
            return "list";
        }

    }
```

when i enter user in admin/users i get link like /admin/usertask?email=rafs@gmail.com where is users tasks

and i want this work with it

```
<div th:each="email:${emaail}">
<a th:href="@{/admin/addTask(email=${email})}" class="btn btn-dark"></a>
</div>
```

but with getattribute it is displayed just after adding task

is there any way to get this email?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking exactly. You are not able to getemail paramater in Get controller class?

Comment: I want to get email from link  /admin/usertask?email=rafs@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the email in usertaks endpoint  `/admin/usertask?email=rafs@gmail.com`

You need to change your controller like this

```
@GetMapping("/admin/usertask")
public String getEmail(@RequestParam("email") String email, Model model,HttpSession session){
    model.addAttribute("task",taskService.findUserTask(email));
    model.addAttribute("emaail",session.getAttribute("email"));
    return "usertasklist";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciated